An analagous statement to finding the covering sheets of a space through the fundamental group index, but with Homology and Cohomology instead?
I know of this following proposition from Hatcher page 62:

Proposition 13.1 The map $$ p_*: \pi_1(\widetilde X , \widetilde x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(X, x_0)$$ induced by a covering space $$ p: (\widetilde X, \widetilde x_0) \rightarrow (X, x_0)$$ is injective. The image subgroup $p_*(\pi_1 (\widetilde X , \widetilde x_0))$ in $\pi_1 (X, X_0)$  consists of the homotopy classes of loops in $X$ based at $x_0$ whose lifts to $\widetilde X$ stating at $\widetilde x_0$ are loops.

I was expecting there to be an analogous statement w.r.t homology or cohomology, but I couldn't find anything of the sort in Hatcher (maybe I missed an example)? I went through his index even, looking for keywords, and couldn't find anything. There are visual similarities to the loops of the fundamental group and the cycles of homology. He mentions the degree of maps in homology, but he only discusses spheres and not much else.

Is there a similar statement that allows me to calculate the number of covering sheets given, say, the first homology groups of both spaces? If and when does a statement of this type hold? As a bonus, I would appreciate any books or chapters that deal with this statement.

The analogous statement for homology is false. For a counterexample, see Hatcher example 1.41 on page 73. The idea is that the orientable surface of genus 11 is a 5-sheeted covering of the orientable surface of genus 3, but $\Bbb Z^{22}$ cannot inject into $\Bbb Z^6$ (consider the first homology).

When $\pi_1(X)$ is abelian, then the analogous statement about injectivity does hold because the Hurewicz map then gives a natural isomorphism with the first homology.

The best I can offer is: For a finite, normal covering, the homology resp. cohomology of $X$ are the coinvariants resp. invariants of the homology resp. cohomology of $\tilde{X}$ under the induced $\pi_1(X)/\pi_1(\tilde{X})$-action for any coefficient group in which $|\pi_1(X)/\pi_1(\tilde{X})|$ is invertible.

Some of these comments can easily be answers.
